# Android AccountManager API

Tags: android

I'm struggling to understand the Android AccountManager API. As far as I got thinks working I can use the blockingGetAuthToken method and specify whether Android should provide a notification for user to allow or deny the request. Another possibility is to use getAuthToken and check if KEY_INTENT is returned. If that's the case I could start a new Activity where the user can confirm my request.

My problem is that I would like to call one of these two methods from within a Service. Is there any chance to get a callback once the user has made a decision?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

If you want a callback after the user has made a decision it's probably better to use the asynchronous version:

```
AccountManager mgr = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
Account[] accounts = mgr.getAccountsByType("com.mydomain");
// assert that accounts is not empty
```

You'll want to use an `AccountManagerFuture<Bundle>` to hold results of the authentication token. This has to be async since the Android device may ask the user to login in the meantime:

```
private AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> myFuture = null;
private AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> myCallback = new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
    @Override public void run(final AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> arg0) {
        try {
           myFuture.getResult().get(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN); // this is your auth token
       } catch (Exception e) {
           // handle error
       }
   }
```

}

Now you can ask for the auth token asynchronously:

```
myFuture = mgr.getAuthToken(accounts[0], AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, true, myCallback, null);
```

Comment: If you want a more comprehensive guide, there you go:
http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator

Comment: @Udinic  can you help how to get asynchronously for getting auth token to pass it through as a param of http request?  app getting crashed when I use blockingGetAuthToken call some time! I have to call async task for for every blockingGetAuthToken call?? http://paste.ubuntu.com/6245277/ in short I'm failed to change void getTokenForAccountCreateIfNeeded to String getTokenForAccountCreateIfNeeded

Comment: @LOG_TAG I don't understand the problem. Why is it crashing? What is the error message you're getting? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Udinic solved it because of load on UI tread, now I'm calling  synchronous blockingGetAuthToken via async task

Comment: @Udinic one more!!also solved the conflict with android:accountType="com.myapp.am" and AccountGeneral class's public static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE = "com.test.app";  please mention i your blog !! :)  I took 3hrs to solve :) if it miss matches it will call binder error!

Comment: @Udinic one more suggetion please for every http request which uses authtoken as param we need to call auth token from account manager is the best way or we can call it once when app starts then use through the app by passing it from activity to activity to speed up the app http request (calling authtoken delay)